# Gell-Mann—Okubo formula

Tags: particle-physics, isospin-symmetry, baryons

How was the Gell-Mann—Okubo formula

$$
M = a_0 + a_1 Y + a_2 \left[ I \left( I + 1 \right)-\frac{1}{4} Y^2 \right] 
$$
rewritten using isospin and strangeness to this formula?

$$\frac{N + \Xi}{2} = \frac{3 \Lambda + \Sigma}{4}$$

The equation comes from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann%E2%80%93Okubo_mass_formula).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just write down the quantum numbers of the baryons in the octet, mindful of $Y=S+B$.
[image]

Use the notation (*Y, I(I+1)*):

N: (1, 3/4) ; Ξ: (-1, 3/4) ; Λ: (0,0) ; Σ: (0,2) .

Using the names of the particles for their masses, then,
and applying the G-O formula additively/subtractively,  you readily see, indeed,
$$
2N + 2\Xi - 3\Lambda -\Sigma\\ =a_0[0]+a_1[2-2]+a_2[2\cdot 3/4+2\cdot 3/4+0-2 -(2+2)/4]\\ =0.
$$